# Array via POST (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, express

Okay, this seems to be the most straight forward thing, but I really have no idea why it's doing this nor find anyone else with this problem.

Here's my issue, I'm sending a POST request like so;

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/user/sell',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('Call was successful');
      }
    });
```

In the data object is an array called `items`. When I log the data object it's fine, like it should be, however when I log the data object in my express function the `items` array changes to `items[]` for no reason..

**NodeJS**

```
'items[]': '15716345'
```

**JS (Browser)**

```
items: [15716345]
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Below is the entire version of the code.
**Entire block (frontend)**
    // Validate address
    if($('.block.payment .wrapper input:eq(0)').val() !== $('.block.payment .wrapper input:eq(1)').val()){
      return error('Fields do not match');
    }

```
// Get known data
var type = $('.body.inventory .methods .method.selected').data('type'),
    items = [];

var data = {
  type,
  address: $('.block.payment .wrapper input:eq(0)').val()
}

if(type === 'steam'){
  var app = $('.body.inventory .sub-methods .method.selected').data('app');
  data['app'] = app;

  $('.body.inventory .item[data-app="'+app+'"].selected').each(function(){
    items.push($(this).data('id'));
  });
}else{
  $('.body.inventory .item[data-type="'+type+'"].selected').each(function(){
    items.push($(this).data('id'));
  });
}

data['items'] = items;

// Execute route or smt
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/user/sell',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Call was successful');
  }
});
```

**Backend**

```
router.post('/sell', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send({
      success: 1
    });
  } catch(e) {
    if(e) console.log(e);

    res.send({
      success: 0,
      error: e
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide NodeJS and JS code for improved understanding.

Comment: Are you using any `logger` library? at node side

Comment: The data you are providing seeming is coming from a form in which you use the `[]` syntax with several inputs to turn them into an array. Are you using FormData?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll add more of the code..

Comment: this seems to be using the raw bodyParser middleware that is specific to form data and not the json bodyParser in expressJS https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserjsonoptions

Answer (score 1):

Set [`JSON` body parser middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserjsonoptions) for requests to your expressJS application.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

And in the AJAX request, make the `contentType` to be `application/json` and not the default of [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: "POST",
  url: '/user/sell',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Call was successful');
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it should as it wraps the body-parser API. The only thing missing maybe is the content-type in the AJAX request you're sending.

Comment: Yeah, I added it but seem to still be having the same result.

Comment: I decided to just send the array over as a string, and then decode it back to an array on the server-side, which works fine. Not sure if it's the best to do, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Assume that is your Array List, which you want to POST.

```
object[] Obj = new object[1];
Obj [0] = "value1"
Obj [1] = "Value2"
Obj [3] = {"CollectionValue1, CollectionValue2"}

$.ajax({
  url: '../Controller/MethodName',
  type: 'post',
  datatype: 'json',
  async: false,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify({ ControllerParameterName: Obj }), <!-- Obj is your Array -->
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data.Response);
  }
});
```